# A function to get the content of a page

Tags: php, functions, pages

I have an Elementor page and I need to get the HTML and CSS output of it without the header and footer to use in an email plugin I am making. Is there a function in WordPress that can do this? I've read about [`WP_Post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_post/) but there is no method to get the content of it. `WP_Post->content` (actually `get_post($post)->content`) doesn't return anything.

Comment: Probably not. It depends how Elementor works. But that's generally not how WordPress pages are structured. You would need to build your theme with this use case in mind from the beginning. Regardless, third party plugins are off topic, so I recommend asking in an Elementor focused forum.

Comment: Can't a static site generator make only one page?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have any function to get the html+css+content of a page for the reason the HTML and CSS is provided by the Theme and the content is stored in the DB.

About Elementor, I don't know exactly how blocks are stored but CSS is in memory created in a physical file.

You can get the content through `the_content` filter hook https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/